# How to stop an animation moving my footer down the page

Tags: html, css

I have an animation in css which moves my footer down the page with each stage as it expands. The animation itself is a text animation like so

```
<div class="fatext">some text</div>
```

Css

```
@media(max-width: 768px){
  .fatext{
    animation: bigger 50s ease forwards;
    animation-delay: 0s;; 
    position:relative;
    font-size: 15px;
    color:#43ff0a;
    bottom: 1700px;
    font-weight:bolder;
    padding: 0px;
    background-color:blue;
    display:block;
  }
} 



@keyframes bigger {from{font-size:0px;} to {font-size:50px}}
```

I've tried:

```
.footer-widget-area {
  position:fixed;
}
```

What can I do with css to stop this?

Comment: Try making your element `position: absolute;`

Comment: But my element needs to be positioned relatively for the animation to work or?

Comment: Can you provide a working example with your HTML?

Comment: You can see working example at https://4309.co.uk in mobile

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE] in the question itself

Comment: @Jon P I did didn't I?

Comment: Not really, see: https://jsfiddle.net/bvjadhe4/ . On top of that `.footer-widget-area ` references something you have given us no information about.